# Is there a way to create a derived instance from a base instance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I want to inject some basic information into a derived class that it can build on. The derived class shouldn't care about initializing those information, it should be just there.

That alone would be easily possible through inheritance. But the problem is that the base class doesn't know the values on its own. Instead, they need to be passed in as parameter. However, since the derived class should not need to take care of that, tunneling the parameters through the derived constructor which calls the base constructor with it is no option.

The only solution I can think of is to make the information available statically so that the base class can get them without help. But I'd like to avoid that.

Is there some way of first creating and initializing the base class and extending the instance to a derived type afterwards? If not, how can I achieve this order of creation and dependencies using the available features of C++?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    Base(string name, int age) : name(name), age(age) {}
protected:
    const string name;
    int age = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
    Derived() { // No parameters here, no call to base constructor
        cout << "My name is " << name << " and I'm " << age << "." << endl;
    }
}

Base base("Peter", 42);
Derived derived(base); // "My name is Peter and I'm 42."
```

Comment: Your "no call to base constructor" makes me answer : No. That's not how C++ works.

Comment: TL;DR; The [Prototype pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/prototype) might help for your use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"The information should just be there" sounds to me like it allows two possible interpretations:

- The information is in fact globally constant and can be hard-coded:

  ```
  Derived() : Base("Peter", 42) {}
  ```
- What you really meant was that "the base should just be there":

  ```
  Derived(const Base & b) : Base(b) {}
  ```

Comment: The information can't be hardcoded. However, the second option looks interesting. Would that use the default copy constructor of `Base` or do I have to implement that myself?

Comment: It will use the default copy unless you provide one

Comment: @danijar: It will use whichever copy constructor of `Base` is selected by overload resolution...

Answer (score 5):

Extending an already-allocated type to a derived type is not possible for a reason: if the derived type added fields, how would you determine the correct size upfront?

A possible way is only a constructor accepting a `Base` instance, or maybe an `operator=`.

**However** you may want to consider using composition over inheritance in this example. If `Base` only serves as template for `Derived`, it is not a good example of an inheritance relationship.

Comment: I consider composition, but it feels wrong. In my application, it's about components that get updated regularly. Composition would mean that the specific components aren't components anymore but normal classes with "jetpacks". My current solution is to provide an additional `void initialize()` method that gets called externally after construction to set the members. However, the values aren't available in the derived constructor then.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use composition, meaning that `Base` would be an instance variable of `Derived`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    Base(string name, int age) : name(name), age(age) {}
    const string name() { return name; }
    int age() { return age; }
protected:
    const string name;
    int age = 0;
};

class Derived {
    Derived(Base b): base(b) { // No parameters here
        cout << "My name is " << base.name() << " and I'm "
             << base.age() << "." << endl;
    }

private:
    Base base;    
}

Base base("Peter", 42);
Derived derived(base); // "My name is Peter and I'm 42."
```

Notice how `Derived` no longer extends `Base` (perhaps the names would need to be changed), and that every call to an instance variable in `Base` is now a method call.